# Default file system for Fedora 27?

Tags: fedora, filesystems, system-installation

Does anyone know what the default file system for Fedora 27 is?

Comment: Does the reference below answer your question? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f27/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda.html

> Starting with Fedora 22, XFS is the default and recommended file system on Fedora Server.

and

> Ext4 is the default and recommended file system used by Fedora Workstation and Cloud